# WPF RichTextBox Image Link issue

Tags: c#, wpf, image, richtextbox

I am loading a .rtf file into a WPF Rich TextBox and my images that have links are getting this underline property added. I do not want the underline and cant seem to get rid of it.

```
              public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();


        Stream s =  assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WPFRichTextIssue.Sigs.MSC.rtf");
        using (s)
        {
             TextRange TR = new TextRange(RTB.Document.ContentStart, RTB.Document.ContentEnd);

        TR.Load(s, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }

    }
```

I have tired to find the underlined images with

```
  if (TR.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) == TextDecorations.Underline)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                // Do something
            }
```

But the Image is not Inline.Text so it does not find it... Any help would be great.

I also thought maybe i could overwrite the Rich Textbox default functionality that causes the underline of links but all i can seem to find to make that change is to the Inline Text nothing for the images and the images are not affected.

The only other option i can think is if there was a way to change the .rtf file to make sure it did not have any underline attributes but unless I am missing something that does not seem to help either.

Entire VS 2012 project issue sample... [Download Project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58943454/WPFRichTextIssue.zip)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in your XAML, just after the RTB opening tag that looks something like this:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="RTB_Reply" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="157" Margin="302,338,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="488" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Paste this:

```
<RichTextBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
        <Setter Property="TextDecorations"  Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
</RichTextBox.Resources>
```

done deal. =D

Comment: That Does fix the issue but now when my user copies this out it still has the underlines :(

Comment: It appears that when you copy that into Outlook signature and save it is still there but once you navigate away and back it is gone so this issue is resolved... And thanks for the help!!!!!!!